# Npm bin script and local file reading

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I've got an npm package that has the `bin` section for running a cli interface utility. One of the dependent scripts of this utility reads a specific file from this package directory via `fs` module.
The definition of the cli util is:

```
"bin": { "my_cli_command": "lib/cli.js" }
```

When I use `npm link` and the cli command locally everything works file.
Like:

```sh
npm link
my_cli_command
```

But after installing the package in another node application run the cli command causes a problem with the script file reading because node rebuilds the `bin` script path:

```sh
npm i --save my_lib
npx my_cli_command
```

There will be an error because `my_cli_command` reads a local package file which is not available now.

Is there a way to allow the npm bin script to read a file from it's own package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved.
Just started using the `path.resolve` method and the `__dirname` variable to compute a file path:

```js
let filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../files/somefile.txt");
```

So that approach will exclude dependency on `cwd` and an npm cli app will be able to work with it's package files without any problem locally or installed in another project.